# is DAO Pattern in Sprint a good one to switch from PostgreSQL To ElasticSearch

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, elasticsearch, dao

I'm new in DAO Pattern and Spring. What i'm trying to do is a webapp that uploads a file(and store it in a file system) and store its metadata on a database(this database could be a postgresql or ElasticSearch but once at a time. There will be two versions of the webAbb that does the same thing but one will use Postgresql and the other one ES). So i'm trying to abstract this and use a DAO that could work with both Postgresql and ES using Spring Tool Suit.
The fact is that I'm not sure if it's possible using DAO Pattern and Spring. I've been looking in the internet and I've found some other interesting patterns such as the [repository Pattern](http://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2014/06/02/The-Repository-Pattern-For-Dummies.aspx). But I can't really see if it would be a better pattern for my webApp.

So I just need an advice, if somebody has ever coded a DAO with Spring in order to work with SQL and NOSQL Database, or if it's not recommended to do so ?

Comment: You should probably look at the [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) projects, in your specific case, [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) (for Postgresql) and [Spring Data Elasticsearch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-elasticsearch/) (for ES).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring CrudRepository is an abstraction and works the same way for ElasticSearch as well RDBMS like PostgreSQL. SpringData has the implementation for ES / CrudRepository

Comment: That seems to be what I was looking for :). I'm going to work on it.